# Simplest way to get first free ID in XML record

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm adding records to XML file. I want to set Id attribute to first free value or last value + 1. (if id's are 1,3,4,7 then id I want to set is 2, if 1,2,3,4 then it is 5).

This is my xml structure

```
<ArrayOfDirectory>
  <Directory Id="0">
    <DirectoryPath>E:\tempFolder1</DirectoryPath>
    <Info>some info</Info>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="2">
    <DirectoryPath>C:\tempFolder2</DirectoryPath>
    <Info>some info</Info>
  </Directory>
</ArrayOfDirectory>
```

This way I'm inserting record to file

```
        WatchedDirectory directoryToSave = (WatchedDirectory)entity;
        XElement newDirectory = new XElement("WatchedDirectory",
            new XAttribute("Id", directoryToSave.Id),
            new XElement("DirectoryPath", directoryToSave.DirectoryPath),
            new XElement("Info","some info"));

        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(DirectoryXmlPath);
        xDocument.Root.Add(newDirectory);
        xDocument.Save(DirectoryXmlPath);
```

My question is what is the simplest way to set first free id when I add new record?

Comment: To get first free ID : xDocument.Descendants("Directory").Where((x,i) => (int)x.Attribute("Id") != i).First();

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following extension method:

```
public static int GetNextSequenceNum(this IEnumerable<int> sequence)
{
    var nums = sequence.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
    var max = nums[nums.Count - 1];
    return Enumerable.Range(0, max + 1)
        .GroupJoin(nums, i => i, i => i, (i, found) =>
        {
            var f = found.ToList();
            if (f.Count == 0)
                return i;
            else
                return (int?)null;
        })
        .First(i => i.HasValue)
        .Value;
}
```

I make no guarantees this is 100% accurate, but you need to:

1. Pull out the id numbers from your XML
2. Pass them into the extension method
3. Out pops the next item in the sequence

For 1,3,4,7 this produces 2
For 1,2,3,4 this produces 5